# Increase buttons hitbox dynamically in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I add buttons inside a FrameLayout (little red dots on an Image). The Problem is that the buttons are to tiny to register clicks properly. I try to increase the hitbox. There are some 5 year old threads on the problem I read. But the mostly focus on increasing padding in the axml file. There is some code using TochDelegate I try to get to work:

```
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        button.GetHitRect(rect);
        rect.Top -= 100;
        rect.Left -= 100;
        rect.Bottom += 100;
        rect.Right += 100;
        frameLayout.AddView(button, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(adjustedSize, adjustedSize));
        ((View)button.Parent).TouchDelegate = new TouchDelegate(rect, button);
```

however it does not change any behaviour as far as I can tell. So is this code wrong and is this really the best way?

thanks

Comment: maybe you just need to add some padding to the button?

Comment: the problem ist that padding seem to do nothing,

Comment: maybe you set it incorrectly? the padding has to do the trick

Comment: what more than button.SetPadding(20,20,20,20); can i do